# Integration of Hotel Reservation Engine with Ruby on Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am looking to build a Ruby on Rails website for a hotel and am trying to figure out what the best approach to  address the integration of a booking engine might be.

Does anyone have had a good experience with a 3rd party booking engine which would integrate relatively well with a Ruby On Rails app ( the hotel is based in Ireland, if that is of any relevance)?

Or is there any gem which could maybe lay the foundations for a reservation engine(all I have seen were event/calendars gems which didn't seem to be maintained anymore)?

Or is it something I should consider building completely from scratch?

Thanks a lot for any suggestion!

Comment: Have you searched here? https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=booking

Comment: Cheers @AnatoliyKukul, I did have a look previously but none of these really seemed to quite fit the bill, except maybe the add-on for Refinery CMS (I'll probably give a quick try, if anything I'll get to get more familiar with Refinery). Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Railscast for quick start: http://railscasts.com/episodes/332-refinery-cms-basics